Variable not accessible inside loop
I have a code snippet as follows:
index = 1
for i=1:n_layers:n_layers*8
    if i==n_layers+1
        Sₐ[i:i+n_layers-1,i:i+n_layers-1] .= func(e_coll[index], correlationMatrix_h2o)
    else
        Sₐ[i:i+n_layers-1,i:i+n_layers-1] .= func(e_coll[index], correlationMatrix)
    end
    index += 1
end

I am getting the following error, and I am unsure why it arises. I have tried declaring it explicitly as a "global" variable but it does not seem to work.
ERROR: UndefVarError: `index` not defined


Did you try to define index as local? local index = 1

Where does this code live? And what version of Julia are you using? This code should always work fine within a function. If used outside a function, at a REPL prompt, it should also work (but did not on Julia 1.0)... the term is "soft global scope", see e.g. here  https://github.com/JuliaLang/SoftGlobalScope.jl?tab=readme-ov-file#hard-and-soft-global-scopes

@mcabbott It does not reside in a function but is a stand-alone code, and the Julia version I am using is 1.10.3.

How are you running this code? From your answers above, my guess would be you have omitted the first line. Specifically, is it possible that (if copy-pasting into the repl, for example), the first line was not ever ran? If you are use include("filelocation"), is it still an issue? Perhaps try explicitly typing that line into the repl.

Ok. If this is at top level in a file you include, or run $ julia file.jl from the shell, or at top level in a module, then it will fail. Soft global scope does not apply in these non-interactive contexts. (It should print an informative warning, before the error.) You can solve it by writing global index inside the for loop. But even better is to put the code in a function.

I believe that cose should work neverthless the soft global scope mess. Try to reduce the example to a minimal self-contained example we can run.
